# How to make an Observable collect values in the stream for x seconds before emitting to subscribes

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Background:** I need to run some code on the router `NavigationStart`event but only when it is not followed by `NavigationCancel`.

I am trying to do this with the following:

```js
const sourceTimer = timer(1000)
this.routerListenersSubscriber = this.router.events
  .pipe(
    map(e => e),
    takeUntil(sourceTimer)
  )
  .subscribe(event => {...})
```

**Want:**
Clearly all this is doing is listening for the router events for 50ms. I would like for it to collect all the values from the `this.router.events` for 50ms before the subscribe gets them so I can check that a `NavigationCancel` event did not happen.

**Edit:** I have tried numerous things, including the variations of the `buffer` operator, but when doing that the issue I am running into is that the stream will only "run" once and then won't run again for subsequent events after the first time's "timer" has run out.

Comment: What do you mean by `subsequent events`?

Comment: @RafiHenig, Let's say the page loads and there are a number of navigation events. They will be collected for the time denoted in `timer` before I can access them in the `subscribe` block. But then let's say I go to another page, none of those router events appear in the 'subscribe' block. It seems like the Observable becomes permanently "cold" after the `timer` ends.

Comment: you can wait in each navigation for `NavigationEnd` without using `takeUntil` so that the observable will never get unsubscribed

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for your question:

```
this.router.events
.pipe(
  takeUntil(timer(50)),
  toArray()
)
.subscribe(events => {
  if(events.any(event => event instanceof NavigationCancel) return 
  else // do your code
})
```

Yet I think the following options are what you're really looking for:

**Option 1.** 
simply complete on `NavigationCancel` using `takeWhile` to prevent the code inside `next` from running.

```js
this.router.events
.pipe(
  takeWhile(x => !(x instanceof NavigationCancel)),
  takeUntil(timer(50)),
  last()
)
.subscribe(x => {
 // run some code ...
})
```

**Option 2.**

```js
this.router.events
  .pipe(
    map(x => x instanceof NavigationCancel ? throwError("NavigationCanceled") : x),
    takeUntil(timer(50)),
  )
  .subscribe({
    complete: () => {
      // run your code here
    },
    error: console.error
  })
```

**Option 3.**

```js
this.router.events
.pipe(
  every(x => !(x instanceof NavigationCancel)),
  takeUntil(timer(50))
)
  .subscribe(x => {
    if (x == true)
    {
      // run your code
    }
  });
```

Comment: First, thank you so much for taking the time to do all of this – huge help! Option 1 actually did what I wanted with the exception of the problem I am running into described in the edit on my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to collect each item that is emitted and then end the subscription with a takeUntil. Make sure the takeUntil is before the reduce.

```js
const { timer } = rxjs;
const { reduce, takeUntil } = rxjs.operators;

timer(500, 500).pipe(
  takeUntil(timer(3000)),
  reduce((results, item) => [...results, item], [])
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-kN8bAZFoIra6Z7dDPNMD3efoGLn7QpOZgBcNpLwKIoBM5rXLVxt9nPHNo+4WrIsT0RBc/h2sXtN08n1ALxn4yw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```